# How to add the libsqlite3.0.dylib in MonoTouch Binding Project?

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, dylib

I want to integrate the [Aviary SDK](http://www.aviary.com/ios) Objective-C library into Monotouch project. I use 'Monotouch Binding Project' template for this. So I have created the API Definition file and define LinkWith Attributes.

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libAviarySDK.a", LinkTarget = LinkTarget.ArmV6 | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator, ForceLoad = true, IsCxx = true, Frameworks="CoreGraphics QuartzCore Accelerate StoreKit CoreData", LinkerFlags="-ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc")]
```

It requires the following libraries:

- Foundation.framework
- UIKit.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- QuartzCore.framework
- Accelerate.framework
- StoreKit.framework
- libz.1.2.5.dylib
- ***libsqlite3.0.dylib***
- CoreData.framework

All these frameworks are linked without problems except the libsqlite3.0.dylib

The problem that I am encountering, though, is that the library depends on **libsqlite3.0.dylib** and I do not know how to include these frameworks in my MonoTouch application.

In a result - compiler returns the following errors:

> /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib -u
>   _catch_exception_raise -force_load /var/folders/2n/ql7wkht57cg8wfgzz0cr9trm0000gn/T/tmp31d0b99b.tmp/libAviarySDK.a
>   -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
>         -[AFLocalyticsDatabase init] in libAviarySDK.a(AFLocalyticsDatabase.o)
>
> "_sqlite3_busy_timeout", referenced from:
>         -[AFLocalyticsDatabase init] in libAviarySDK.a(AFLocalyticsDatabase.o)
>
> "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
>         -[AFLocalyticsDatabase beginTransaction:] in libAviarySDK.a(AFLocalyticsDatabase.o)
>
> *** *And many other same references* ***
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 collect2: ld returned
>   1 exit status
>
> mtouch exited with code 1

Comment: In case you are using sharpie to generate from cocoapods, you can take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752620/linking-libz-dylib-and-libsqlite3-dylib-in-xamarin-ios-project/39307966#39307966

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `-lsqlite3.0` to your `LinkerFlags` for your binding to instruct the (native) linker to load the SQLite library (and symbols).

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("your_lib.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7, ForceLoad = true, LinkerFlags="-lsqlite3.0")]
```

Comment: I too am working to link in Aviary - could you provide some details about how you got this working?